# PostgreSQL: What is the fastest way to backup/restore individual tables or table partitions (data+indexes)

Tags: postgresql, performance, backup, restore

I'm migrating from a proprietary dbms to PG. In the proprietary dbms, "offlining" and "onlining" data partitions is a very lightweight operation. I'm looking to implement similar functionality with PG by backup and restore of individual table (partitions). Obviously I need to avoid a performance regression. So my question is what the fastest way is of:

- Backing up a table (partition), both data and indexes
- Taking the table offline (meaning that the data is now gone from the database)
- Restoring the table (partition), both data and indexes

Once I have some advice I can design more targeted performance comparisons. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

What is fast and needs to be fast is adding or removing a partition (`ALTER TABLE ... ATTACH/DETACH PARTITION`).

After you have detached the partition you are in no great hurry to backup/export the data. This can be done comfortably with `pg_dump`.

Similarly, importing the data for a table that is to become a new partition is normally not time critical.

If you need this to happen faster (for example, you want the old partition to be visible in another database as soon as it is detached in the old one), you could use *logical replication* to replicate the partition to another PostgreSQL database *before* you detach it. As soon as replication has caught up, you detach or drop the original partition and attach the copy in the other database.

Comment: Actually, backup performance is not critical, but restore is. I need to bring data partitions (table partition backups) back online when needed (in fairly large numbers). Overall application performance will suffer is this is not fast.

Comment: Well, then logical replication is the way to go (requires PostgreSQL >= v10).

Comment: I don't want my data "online" in any database as long as I don't need it. But if I do, I want it to be online quickly. So really, logcal replication does not help me.
Does PG have a way to online a table (partiton) quickly? That is, of course including indices. If re-indexing is part of the onlining, then it will never be quick enough for my use-case. This is what I'm trying to assess. If it can't be done, I'll look for an alternative.

Comment: There is no way to get lots of data into a database quickly, if that's what you mean with "to online". There is the option to define an "external table" based on a CSV file using `file_fdw`, which is very fast, but of course there is no index then (do historical data really need to be that fast?). Other than that, you have to keep the data in a database, but it need not be accessible (-->permissions), if that is your concern.